# Set timezone on embedded Linux system

Tags: linux, timezone

I have a small uCLinux system, how do I set the timezone on uCLinux?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Can you please explain what makes this question on topic here on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

If the system uses BusyBox, add this command to `/etc/inittab`:

```
setenv TZ PDT
```

If not using busybox, just set an environment variable in your application's initialization code:

```
putenv ("TZ=PDT");
```

I have chosen US Pacific Daylight Time for these examples, but maybe that does not apply to you.

Comment: Sounds good, will try it out soon.  Where do I get the official list of timezone names from?  E.g. "PDT" etc.?

Comment: @fredbasset:  The U.S. values are at http://www.worldtimezone.com/time-usa12.php  A link near the left-bottom goes to http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz-names/timezonenames.html which looks pretty thorough.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion but it's not working yet, the system time as reported by the "date" command is still in UTC.  The TZ env. var. is definitely set to "PDT".  I'm using Busybox busybox-1.11.2 and using ntpclient from Larry Doolittle (http://doolittle.icarus.com/ntpclient/).

Comment: Sorry, the file is `/etc/inittab` (my fault for not looking).  See the [busybox inittab documentation](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/examples/inittab?h=1_5_stable&=switch).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm still stuck at UTC however.  My inittab runs /etc/rc.d/rcS and in there I export TZ=PDT (my system doesn't have setenv), and TZ is definitely being set and is available to the subsequent script that runs the ntpclient.  The log entries in /var/log/messages are all in UTC, as is the output of the date command, so something is still not right.

Comment: @fredbasset:  Are you sure that NTP uses localtime?  I tried to look on my boxes, but NTP is not in use.  HTTP definitely uses localtime, and notes the timezone: `192.168.0.103 - - [25/Mar/2012:14:15:54 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14`  Maybe you could temporarily modify the NTP startup script to `echo $TZ`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9289/discussion-between-fred-basset-and-wallyk)

Comment: @fredbasset:  I added stuff at the chat location, but the information there suggests neither of us have enough reputation to talk.  Can you see my comments?

Answer (score 2):

I export TZ=PDT (my system doesn't have `setenv`), and TZ is definitely being set and is available to the subsequent script that runs the `ntpclient`. The log entries in `/var/log/messages` are all in UTC, as is the output of the date command.

```
export TZ=PST8PDT
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile` appending the following line:

```
TZ='Asia/Kolkata'; export TZ
```

Then log out and log in again.